# Can you use jQuery's outerHeight function with an int parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm working on a jQuery function to set the height of a div based on the height of the window and some other elements, and I noticed something strange. The outerHeight() function seems to accept an integer parameter, even though [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) doesn't specify that one is allowed.

So this seems to work in both Chrome and Firefox:

```
var o_height = $("#content").outerHeight();
var n_height = $(window).outerHeight() - $("#nav").outerHeight();

if (n_height > o_height) {
    $("#content").outerHeight(n_height);
}
```

The alternative is to calculate the padding and then subtract it, which is a few lines longer:

```
var o_height = $("#content").outerHeight();   
var n_height = $(window).outerHeight() - $("#nav").outerHeight();

if (n_height > o_height) {
    var padding = $("#content").outerHeight() - $("#content").height();
    $("#content").height(n_height - padding); 
}
```

What I'm wondering is whether it's safe to use the shorter version. I'll be doing stuff like this several times, so I'd rather cut down on the length of the script, but not at the cost of stability. Is this a stable, but undocumented feature, or do I just need to accept the extra weight in the function?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else stumbles upon this, it appears that this functionality was actually added all the way back in [1.8.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/e0151e5827d7091f311c82d9f951aaaa2688ba8c) for both outerHeight and outerWidth, but that [despite frequent reports](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/98), the documentation still hasn't been updated.